# Values (int, struct-values) from initWithCoder are lost outside this method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

I am quite new to objective-c and got stuck with a quite simple task I assume. I use Xcode 4.0.1 and my deployment target is OS X 10.6.

I save and load some plain C `ints` s and struct values by using `encodeWithCoder` and `initWithCoder`.
This works quite good - the saved values are loaded and I can `NSLog` them in the `initWithCoder` method.

But when I want to use these loaded values in an other method, they are all gone. But I can not see why or where the values are lost.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

My Header file:

```
@interface OptimiererZwoAppDelegate : NSDocument <NSApplicationDelegate,NSCoding> {

//Winkel in Grad
__strong struct bildanalyse { 
    float winkelo;
    float winkelr;
    ... here are some more variables…
    float skalfak;   
};

__strong struct bildanalyse *analyse;
__strong int16_t anzahlanalysewerte;


...some more stuff....
}
...
- (NSData *) dataOfType:(NSString *)aType error:(NSError **)outError;
- (BOOL) readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError;
- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder;
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder;
...

@property __strong struct bildanalyse *analyse;
@property __strong int16_t anzahlanalysewerte;
...
```

And this is my implementation file:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    ...some code...
    [self prepareApp]; 
}


-(void) prepareApp{
    NSLog(@"prepareApp");
    self.analyse = NSAllocateCollectable(sizeof(struct bildanalyse) * 256, 0); 
    self.anzahlanalysewerte = 0;
}


- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder{

    [coder encodeInt:self.anzahlanalysewerte forKey: @"anzahlanalysewerte"];

    for(int i=0; i< self.anzahlanalysewerte; i++){
        [coder encodeFloat:self.analyse[i].winkelo forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"winkelo%d",i]];
        [coder encodeFloat:self.analyse[i].winkelr forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"winkelr%d",i]];
        ...
        [coder encodeFloat:self.analyse[i].skalfak forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skalfak%d",i]];
    }
}

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder{
    self = [super init];
    [self prepareApp]; 
    self.anzahlanalysewerte = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"anzahlanalysewerte"];

    for(int i=0; i< self.anzahlanalysewerte; i++){
        self.analyse[i].winkelo = [coder decodeFloatForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"winkelo%d",i]];
        self.analyse[i].winkelr = [coder decodeFloatForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"winkelr%d",i]];
        ...
        self.analyse[i].skalfak = [coder decodeFloatForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skalfak%d",i]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Objective-C dot syntax to set the value of struct members if you are referring to the struct itself via dot syntax as an Objective-C property. In fact, the compiler should warn you about this.

To illustrate, if `foo` is a struct with a member `bar`, you cannot do this:

```
anObjCobject.foo.bar = 42;
```

However, you can assign an entire struct to the property like this:

```
foobar.bar = 42; // where foobar is a struct of the same type as foo
anObjCobject.foo = foobar;
```

The confusion probably stems from the fact that you *can* access the value of a struct member that is a property of an Objective-C object using dot notation:

```
NSLog("%lu", anObjCobject.foo.bar); //outputs 42, perfectly legal
```

It's just setters that are the problem, getters work fine with dot notation.

Also, you should also avoid using accessors in `‑init` methods, you should instead set the ivars directly.

You will need to end up with something like this:

```
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        [self prepareApp]; 
        anzahlanalysewerte = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"anzahlanalysewerte"];

        //self.analyse needs to be malloc'd to accomodate the size of anzahlanalysewerte as well
        for(int i=0; i< self.anzahlanalysewerte; i++)
        {

            bildanalyse foo;
            foo.winkelo = [coder decodeFloatForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"winkelo%d",i]];
            foo.winkelr = [coder decodeFloatForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"winkelr%d",i]];
            ...
            foo.skalfak = [coder decodeFloatForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skalfak%d",i]];

            analyse[i] = foo;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried it with your sugestions but had no luck.
The result is still the same.
I forgot to mention, that I use garbage collection - but I think that you already assumed that.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder` implementation? If you did not implement it that is probably your problem, if you did implement it please post that as well. Also you are trying to access a struct pointer directly so you should make sure self is not nil in `initWithCoder:`.

```
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        [self prepareApp]; 
        self.anzahlanalysewerte = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"anzahlanalysewerte"];

        //self.analyse needs to be malloc'd to accomodate the size of anzahlanalysewerte as well
        for(int i=0; i< self.anzahlanalysewerte; i++){
            self.analyse[i].winkelo = [coder decodeFloatForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"winkelo%d",i]];
            self.analyse[i].winkelr = [coder decodeFloatForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"winkelr%d",i]];
            ...
            self.analyse[i].skalfak = [coder decodeFloatForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skalfak%d",i]];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note: When you conform to a protocol you do not need to add the methods of that protocol to the header file. You can safely remove both `- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder;` and `- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder;` from the header.

Comment: I did't post the encodeWithCoder implementaion because I think the problem can not be in this method. If it were there, then I wouldn't be able to see the right values in initWithCoder.
But I added it to my question now.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your input. The main problem in my application was, that I did not implemented the multi-document-architecture in the correct way. That lead to wrong handling of the various window-instances.
I have fixed that now - but still loose the values of my instance variables after reading them by initWithCoder. But I think the situation is quite different now. That for I will post this in a new question.
Thank you again for all your affords!